# How to check if there is a specialization for std::less, using concepts?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, c++-concepts

I'm trying to create a concept to check if there is a specialization for the std::less.

Seeing the concept example for std::hash on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), I've created the code below:

```
#include <bit>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename DataType >
concept Lessable = requires(DataType value1, DataType value2)
{
    { std::less < DataType > {}(value1, value2) } -> std::convertible_to < bool >;
};

template < typename DataType >
concept Hashable = requires(DataType value)
{
    { std::hash < DataType > {}(value) } -> std::convertible_to < size_t >;
};

// Specialization for std::less < std::complex < float > >.
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct less < std::complex < float > >
    {
        bool operator()(const std::complex < float > &number1, const std::complex < float > &number2) const
        {
            return number1.real() < number2.real() ||
                number1.real() == number2.real() && number1.imag() < number2.imag();
        }
    };
}

// Specialization for std::hash < std::complex < float > >.
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash < std::complex < float > >
    {
        size_t operator()(const std::complex < float > &number1) const
        {
            return std::hash < float > {}(number1.real()) ^ std::rotl(std::hash < float > {}(number1.imag()), 1);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Lessable < std::complex < float > > << "\n";
    std::cout << Hashable < std::complex < float > > << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason I do not understand, the `Hashable` works as intended, returning true, if the specialization is present; and false, if the specialization is not present.

But the `Lessable` always returns true, no matter if the specialization is present or not.
Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and what must I do to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Testing on `std::complex` is to blame https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/library#namespace.std-2 - try a custom type.

Comment: If you could explain _why_ you want to do this in your question - what you're hoping to achieve with this knowledge - we may be able to help you solve _that_ problem in a different way.

Comment: It is a bit hard to explain what I'm trying to achieve... But, with Nicol Bolas' answer, I think I can solve my problem in another way.
Anyhow, thanks for your attention, Casey!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any type that is less-than comparable is comparable with `std::less`. That is, the primary `std::less` template will invoke `operator<` for any `T` it is given. You *can* provide an explicit specialization for some user-defined type, but you don't have to if your type is `operator<` comparable.

`std::complex` is not less-than comparable by nature. However, you're not allowed to provide specializations for a standard library template if the all of the template parameters for the specialization are *themselves* standard-library types. Trying to do so achieves UB, so you could get any result.

But in any case, `std::hash` is something you *must* provide a specialization for. That's part of what it means to make a type "hashable".

These are two different designs for different kinds of functionality. A type can implicitly be less-than comparable, but a type cannot implicitly be hashable.

And no, there is no way to detect with a concept whether a particular template instantiation comes from a primary template or a specialization.

If what you're trying to do is see if a type is less-than comparable, you shouldn't be relying on `std::less` at all. Instead, you should be using the [`std::totally_ordered` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/totally_ordered).